# Simple camel ftp route timeout

Tags: java, apache, ftp, apache-camel

I configured a simple route inside a test class see below:

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestClass extends CamelTestSupport {   
    String ftpSourceUri = "ftp://some.server.com:21?username=user&password=secret&fileName=test.csv";


    @Test
    public void testRouteConsumesTestFileFromFTPEndpoint() throws Exception{
        MockEndpoint mock = getMockEndpoint("mock:result");
        mock.expectedMinimumMessageCount(1);
        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from(ftpSourceUri)
                .multicast().to("mock:result","stream:out");

            }
        };
    }
}
```

I have validated the authentication details and the file location via FileZilla.

> This is the trace snippet produced by camel when I execute the above
>   code:
>
> [                          main] DefaultCamelContext            INFO 
>   Apache Camel 2.14.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting [
>   main] DefaultManagementStrategy      INFO  JMX is disabled [
>   main] DefaultTypeConverter           INFO  Loaded 192 type converters
>   [                          main] DefaultCamelContext            INFO 
>   AllowUseOriginalMessage is enabled. If access to the original message
>   is not needed, then its recommended to turn this option off as it may
>   improve performance. [                          main]
>   DefaultCamelContext            INFO  StreamCaching is not in use. If
>   using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more
>   details at [                          main] DefaultCamelContext
>   INFO  Route: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint['endpoint
>   url'] <-- I can't post more than 2 links apparently  [
>   main] DefaultCamelContext            INFO  Total 1 routes, of which 1
>   is started. [                          main] DefaultCamelContext
>   INFO  Apache Camel 2.14.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.140
>   seconds [                          main] MockEndpoint
>   INFO  Asserting: Endpoint[mock://result] is satisfied
>   [tal-music-ftp.amazonmp3.com:21] FtpConsumer                    INFO 
>   Connected and logged in to: ['endpoint url'] <-- I can't post more
>   than 2 links apparently  [                          main]
>   AmazonMP3SimpleFTPRouteTest    INFO 
>   ******************************************************************************** [                          main] AmazonMP3SimpleFTPRouteTest    INFO 
>   Testing done:
>   testRouteConsumesTestFileFromFTPEndpoint(com.test.camel.SimpleFTPRouteTest)
>   [                          main] AmazonMP3SimpleFTPRouteTest    INFO 
>   Took: 10.010 seconds (10010 millis) [                          main]
>   AmazonMP3SimpleFTPRouteTest    INFO 
>   ******************************************************************************** [                          main] DefaultCamelContext            INFO 
>   Apache Camel 2.14.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down [
>   main] DefaultShutdownStrategy        INFO  Starting to graceful
>   shutdown 1 routes (timeout 10 seconds) [el-1) thread #1 -
>   ShutdownTask] DefaultShutdownStrategy        INFO  Waiting as there
>   are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 10
>   seconds. [el-1) thread #1 - ShutdownTask] DefaultShutdownStrategy
>   INFO  Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to
>   complete, timeout in 9 seconds. [el-1) thread #1 - ShutdownTask]
>   DefaultShutdownStrategy        INFO  Waiting as there are still 1
>   inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 8 seconds.
>   [el-1) thread #1 - ShutdownTask] DefaultShutdownStrategy        INFO 
>   Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to
>   complete, timeout in 7 seconds. [el-1) thread #1 - ShutdownTask]
>   DefaultShutdownStrategy        INFO  Waiting as there are still 1
>   inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 6 seconds.
>   [el-1) thread #1 - ShutdownTask] DefaultShutdownStrategy        INFO 
>   Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to
>   complete, timeout in 5 seconds. [el-1) thread #1 - ShutdownTask]
>   DefaultShutdownStrategy        INFO  Waiting as there are still 1
>   inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 4 seconds.
>   [el-1) thread #1 - ShutdownTask] DefaultShutdownStrategy        INFO 
>   Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to
>   complete, timeout in 3 seconds. [el-1) thread #1 - ShutdownTask]
>   DefaultShutdownStrategy        INFO  Waiting as there are still 1
>   inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 2 seconds.
>   [el-1) thread #1 - ShutdownTask] DefaultShutdownStrategy        INFO 
>   Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to
>   complete, timeout in 1 seconds. [                          main]
>   DefaultShutdownStrategy        WARN  Timeout occurred. Forcing the
>   routes to be shutdown now.  Some resources may still be running.
>   [el-1) thread #1 - ShutdownTask] DefaultShutdownStrategy        WARN 
>   Interrupted while waiting during graceful shutdown, will force
>   shutdown now. [el-1) thread #1 - ShutdownTask] DefaultShutdownStrategy
>   INFO  Route: route1 shutdown complete, was consuming from:
>   Endpoint['endpoint url'] <-- I can't post more than 2 links apparently
>   [                          main] DefaultShutdownStrategy        INFO 
>   Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 52 seconds [
>   main] DefaultCamelContext            INFO  Apache Camel 2.14.0
>   (CamelContext: camel-1) uptime 1 minute [
>   main] DefaultCamelContext            INFO  Apache Camel 2.14.0
>   (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutdown in 52.486 seconds

What can  I do to simply download the file?

Comment: **camel-ftp 2.14.0**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MockEndpoint will by default timeout after 10 seconds from unit testing. So you need to set a higher wait time for the FTP to download and process the file.

You can pass in a timeout value in, for example

```
assertMockEndpointsSatisfied(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Is there any particular reason the above setup would work with a sftp, and not a ftp, endpoint?